# Query to eliminate multiple rows based on oldest date

Tags: ms-access, date, rows

Working in MS Access 2003 SP3: I have a query that I am running to find what 'cars' were sold with a date after the delivery date. I have thousands of rows. When it is all said and done, I want to just have a handful of rows for each 'car' and then the oldest date. Any suggestions?

```
CAR          DATE ORDERED   DATE DELIVERED  CUSTOMER NUMBER DATE SOLD
FORD MUSTANG    20061002             20080413            ABC123          20080422
FORD MUSTANG    20061002             20080413            ABC124          20080429
CHEVY IMPALA    20061002             20080413            ABC125          20080505
```

Comment: Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might find you'll get more answers if you accept some (but not necessarily all) of the answers for your other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be better if you had an ID field:

```
DELETE 
FROM Cars
WHERE Cars.DATESOLD Not In (
             SELECT TOP 5 DateSold 
             FROM Cars c 
             WHERE c.Car=Cars.Car 
             ORDER BY DateSold DESC) 
And Cars.DATESOLD Not In (
             SELECT TOP 1 DateSold 
             FROM Cars c 
             WHERE c.Car=Cars.Car 
             ORDER BY DateSold)
```

If there are duplicate dates, you will end up with more than 5 records.